# Coarse Graining: Correlation destroyed after coarse graining

Tags: statistics

X Y  are two correlated random variable. How likely the correlation between them will be destroyed if the following coarse graining method is applied on them? We divide the range of X and that of Y into a finite number (m say) of cells. We take the expectation value of X in each cell(i) as Xi. P(X_i) is the integral of f(X) within i. It is the same for Y. Let us note X and Y after coarse graining X' and Y'. Given X and Y are correlated, can we specify when the correlation between X' and Y' will be lost after coarse graining?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is too vague for a precise general answer.
The change in correlation with 'coarse graining' will depend on
the original correlation, the distributions of the two variables,
and the sample size, as well as on the number $m$ of cells. However the issues raised are important and interesting.

The correlation $r_{xy}$ of $n$ bivariate observations $(X_i,Y_i)$ is defined in terms of the covariance $s_{xy}$
as $$r_{xy} = \frac{s_{xy}}{\sqrt{s_xs_y}},$$ where $s_x$ and $s_y$ are the sample standard deviations and the covariance is defined as
$$s_{xy} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)(Y_i = \bar Y)}{n-1}.$$

With respect to the center of the data cloud at $(\bar X, \bar Y),$ each of the $n$ products $(X_i - \bar X)(Y_i = \bar Y)$ may lie in one of four 'quadrants.'
The product above and to the right of center and those below and to the left make positive contributions to the covariance. Those in the other two quadrants make negative contributions. Especially if your 'graining' results in moving a substantial number of observations from a quadrant of one
sign to a quadrant of another sign, the effect on $s_{xy}$ and thus on $r_{xy}$ will be relatively large. Also, points farthest from
the center can make the largest contributions to the numerator of $s_{xy},$ and
even slight changes in them might make a large difference in $r_{xy}.$

One important application akin to your idea of 'graining' is rounding. Rounding is a little different in that it moves points to
predetermined points rather than to cell means. But a lot is known
about rounding, and that may help you in refining your question
about graining.

**Effect of rounding on sample correlation.**

Roughly speaking, slight rounding does not have much effect on sample means, standard deviation or correlation. However, severe rounding can make important differences. I will illustrate with a couple
of simulated normal datasets with $n = 1000.$

In the first example $r = r_{xy}$ is nearly $1.$ For unrounded
data there are 1000 distinct datapoints and $r = .9999$ (to 4 places). 
Rounding to one decimal place produces about 60 distinct points all very near the 45-degree line (many ties) and $r = .9997$ is hardly changed. Rounding to integers produces about a dozen distinct points, about half noticeably far from the 45-degree line, and $r = .9978.$

```
# Generate data
x = sort(rnorm(2000))
x1 = x[seq(1,1999,by=2)];  x2 = x[seq(2,2000,by=2)]

# Find correlations
cor(x1,x2)                      # r for original data
## 0.9998576
cor(round(x1,1), round(x2,1))   # rounded to one place
## 0.9997155
cor(round(x1), round(x2))       # rounded to integers
## 0.9977589
```

The second dataset is sampled from a bivariate normal distribution
with means 0, variances 1.25, and $\rho = 0.8.$
The correlation of the original 1000 datapoints is $r = .7904,$ and
rounding to one place makes no substantial difference. By 
contrast, rounding to integers produces about 30 distinct
plotting points (again many ties). Of these, 8 lie exactly
on the 45-degree line. Also, 9 of the 30 have one or both
values rounded to 0; altogether, over half of the original
data now make no contribution to the numerator of the covariance.
The correlation $r = .7373$ of the data rounded to integers is substantially different, but hardly "destroyed."

```
 u = rnorm(1000); v = rnorm(1000)  # independent
 x1 = u+.5*v;  x2 = v+.5*u         # correlated
 cor(x1,x2)
 ## 0.7904387
 cor(round(x1,1),round(x2,1))
 ## 0.791321
 cor(round(x1),round(x2))
 ## 0.737281
```

I can imagine that, judiciously done, your 'graining' might have somewhat less effect than rounding---because
you are using data-weighted centers for your cells whereas
rounding pretty much uses geometric centers. However, precisely
that difference may make it more difficult to get a useful 
solution (analytic or simulated) for particular bivariate distributions and
sample sizes.

*Note:* The simulations and computations above use R statistical software
available free of charge from r-project.org.